# How can I negate this conditional statement?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The conditional statement is: 
If today is February 1, then tomorrow is Ground Hog's Day.
I need to negate this but I am confused. Would it just be If today is not February 1, then tomorrow is not Ground Hog's Day? I think that is an inverse statement though. Please help me negate this conditional statement.

Comment: Please don't insert superfluous tags in your questions. This question isn't about probability or functions. Thanks!

Comment: @Jsevillamol No, it’s not. Your two statements are equivalent.

Comment: Maybe it will help you to use the following: “If A then B” is equivalent to “(Not A) or B”.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: The negation of an implication is not an implication again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let$$p: \text{today is February 1}$$
$$q: \text{tomorrow is Ground Hog's Day}$$
Then your statement is, $$p\rightarrow q$$

**Informally** the negation of `"If p then q"` is **p and *not* q**,

i.e. $\color{green}{\text{today is February 1}}$  and $\color{red}{\text{tomorrow is not Ground Hog's Day}}$.

**More formally**

$$p\rightarrow q \text{ is equivalent to } (\lnot p\lor q)$$ And

$$\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)\equiv\lnot\lnot p\land\lnot q\equiv p\land\lnot q.$$ by DeMorgan laws.

Comment: very helpful thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The negation would formally be "Today is february the first and tomorrow is not Ground Hog's Day". The reason is that an implication $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ is the same as $\neg\phi\lor\psi$, then negating this using DeMorgan laws you get $\neg(\neg\phi\lor\psi) \equiv \neg\neg\phi\land\neg\psi \equiv \phi\land\neg\psi $

You could also reasoning that the only way an implication is false if the premise is true, yet the consequence is false.